# how to set maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes in next.js

Tags: caching, next.js, progressive-web-apps, webpack-5

i'm using next.js and for cache problem i use

```
 webpack: (config) => {
    config.output.filename = "[name].[contenthash].js";
    return config;
  },
```

in next.config.js so i got this error :
_next/pages/_app-796ac14b74708832.js.map is 2.53 MB, and won't be precached. Configure maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes to change this limit.

where and how can i set maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes  ?

i try

```
  webpack: (config ) => {
    config.output.filename =  "[name].[contenthash].js",
    config.maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes = 5000000
    return config
  },
```

and got error again